# If i write a very long article, bottom of it goes into the footer and cant be read, while the header shifts downwards

Tags: html, css

If i write a very long article, bottom of the text goes behind the footer and cant be read, while the header (navbar) at the top shifts downwards. The footer is fixed. The header should stay where it is. However I can see that the text that i provide in the section basically wraps around the logo on the top left, while the navbar connected to the logo which is floated left shifts downwards, below the logo.  stays above the navbar while the rest of the text () is below the navbar. I have been trying to fix it for hours but couldn't. Thanks for reading. If insufficient for answer, which parts of the HTML code do i have to provide? Thanks!

This is the CSS code.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: arial;
}

.container {
}

header,section,footer{
    display: block;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

.top_nav {
    float: left;
    width: 1400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0080ff;
}

.top_nav ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;

}

a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #198cff;

}

a:visited{
    color: white;
}

input.gobutton{
    width:69%;
    cursor:pointer; 
    padding:5px 25px; 
    background:#A87300; 
    border:1px solid #A87300; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    color:#f3f3f3;
    font-size:1.1em;
}
input.gobutton:hover, input.gobutton:focus{
    background-color :#825A03; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
}

.page_footer {
    float: left;
    width: 1600px;
    background-color: #0080ff;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

section a:link {
    color: blue;
}

section a:visited {
    color: blue;
}

.keybotimg {
    padding-left:30%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

section div{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 900px

}

section div p{
text-align: left;
}

section div p h2,h4{
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: hi can you provide html or update your html and css code with jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you say your footer is fixed. This means it will stay where it is no matter what. Try setting it to float.

Comment: I need the footer to follow the viewport. Float won't do that. I just need a way to prevent the text going behind this footer. The main problem is however the navigation bar, the header. It shifts down when i write a lot of stuff. How to fix those?